# AccessDeniedException Error deleting EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I've successfully created an EKS cluster and some other resources via a terraform script. However, I am unable to successfully complete the terraform destroy. I get the following error upon deletion of EKS cluster:

```
Error: error deleting EKS Cluster (cluster-name): AccessDeniedException:
    status code: 403, request id: request-uuid
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the cluster deletion command ?

Comment: The resources are specified in terraform scripts, `terraform destroy` will destroy everything that was created

Comment: Seems like either the `cluster-name` is already deleted or the user or role you're using does not have access to delete eks clusters.

Comment: Yes, I've resolved this, appreciate the response!! @SomeGuyOnAComputer

Answer (score 0):

The role I'm using needs to allow the eks:DeleteCluster operation in its policy.